# Empty DataFrame in pandas after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am following examples in [Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Data-Analysis-Wrangling-IPython/dp/1449319793), and keep coming across a problem: once I merge the DataFrames that I have created, the merged DF is showing as an empty DF, even though the component DFs are showing as being populated.

The code is:

```
data = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)
```

Then when I check `data`, it shows as empty:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [user_id, rating, timestamp, gender, age, occupation, zip, movie_id, title, genres]
Index: []
```

When I check the component DFs, they all contain data:

```
In [65]: len(ratings)
Out[65]: 1000209

In [66]: len(movies)
Out[66]: 3883

In [67]: len(users)
Out[67]: 6040
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: By default when you  pass no args to `merge` it will perform an inner merge on all the columns, you get an empty df because you have no rows where all column values agree

Comment: I think there is problem with different `dtype` of joined column - e.g. in one `df` it is `object` and in another `int`

Comment: Can you add small data samples to question?

Comment: @EdChum Then why is it that the example in the book shows that when I view the `data` DF, it should have a huge list of data?

Comment: I can't comment without raw data and code but the fact remains the behaviour of that method and code you posted is to only merge where the common columns contain the same values for all rows, en empty df means no rows met that criteria

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to merge on 2 indexes. I can't tell without more code if that's your issue i.e are you sure you commented out any earlier code that may be setting the indexes of both dfs to something that can't match... As mentioned in the comments, I also tried to solve it by making sure my matching columns were the same dtype (see code below). Both were already object types, so it can't have been the issue.

```
print(df_movies.dtypes)

print(df_ratings.dtypes)
```

Then I tried setting both dataframes indexes to the same columns I was matching on. This worked for me:

```
df_movies = df_movies.set_index('movie_id')
        
df_ratings = df_ratings.set_index('movie_id')
    
df_mov_rating = pd.merge(df_movies, df_ratings, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```